# In a bash pipe, take the output of the previous command as a variable to the next command (Eg. if statement)

Tags: bash, if-statement, pipe, conditional-statements

I wanted to write a command to compare the hash of a file. I wrote the below single line command. Wanted to understand as to how I can take the output of the previous command as a variable for the current command, in a pipe.

Eg. below command I wanted to compare the output of 1st command "Calculated hash" to the original hash. In the last command, I wanted to refer to the output of the previous command. How do I do that in the if statement? (Instead of `$0`)

```
sha256sum abc.txt | awk '{print $1}' | if [ "$0" = "8237491082roieuwr0r9812734iur" ]; then
    echo "match"
fi
```

Comment: See the code given in my answer working correctly at https://ideone.com/RoyCH8

Comment: That said, have you considered `sha256sum abc.txt | awk -v good="...hash..." '$1 == good { print "match"; }`? No reason for shell to do something the copy of awk you're already running can take care of itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following your narrow request looks like:

```
sha256sum abc.txt  |
  awk '{print $1}' |
  if [ "$(cat)" = "8237491082roieuwr0r9812734iur" ]; then echo "match"; fi
```

...as `cat` with no arguments reads the command's stdin, and in a pipeline, content generated from prior stages are streamed into their successors.

Alternately:

```
sha256sum abc.txt  |
  awk '{print $1}' |
  if read -r line && [ "$line" = "8237491082roieuwr0r9812734iur" ]; then echo "match"; fi
```

...wherein we `read` only a single line from stdin instead of using `cat`. (To instead loop over all lines given on stdin, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)).

---

However, I would strongly suggest writing this instead as:

```
if [ "$(sha256sum abc.txt | awk '{print $1}')" = "8237491082roieuwr0r9812734iur" ]; then
  echo "match"
fi
```

...which, among other things, keeps your logic outside the pipeline, so your `if` statement can set variables that *remain* set after the pipeline exits. See [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for more details on the problems inherent in running code in pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `sha256sum`'s check mode. If you save the output of `sha256sum` to a file, you can check it with `sha256sum -c`.

```
$ echo foo > file        
$ sha256sum file > hash.txt
$ cat hash.txt
b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c  file
$ sha256sum -c hash.txt
file: OK
$ if sha256sum -c --quiet hash.txt; then echo "match"; fi
```

If you don't want to save the hashes to a file you could pass them in via a [here-string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/command-line-instead-of):

```
if sha256sum -c --quiet <<< 'b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c  file'; then
    echo "match"
fi
```

Comment: This requires me to save the original hash from the website to be saved in a file in the given format in the same folder as the `file`. ie. `b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c  file` to be saved in a hash.txt. isn't it?

Comment: You can skip the file by using a here-string. See the second part of my answer.

Comment: `if echo 'b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c  file' | sha256sum -c --quiet; then echo 'match'; fi` without the herestring maybe?